# Change location of folder "Microsoft Teams Chat Files"

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

The folder `/Microsoft Teams Chat Files` (and also `/Notebooks`) is autogenerated by Microsoft Teams and it sits at the root of my professional OneDrive account in a Office 365 subscription.

I would like to change the location of this folder, putting it in a subfolder like `./microsoft/office`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Symlinks.

Symlinks, or symbolic links, are “virtual” files or folders which reference a physical file or folder located elsewhere, and are an important feature built in to many operating systems, including Linux and Windows.

A symlink is essentially a pointer to a file or folder located elsewhere, consumes little space and is very fast to create (compared to copying a file and its contents).

The syntax is simple, for example:

`mklink /H Link Target`

/H means that you'll make a "hard" link, as opposed to a "soft" or "symbolic" link.

When you open a soft link to a folder, you will be redirected to the folder where the files are stored.  However, a hard link makes it appear as though the file or folder actually exists at the location of the symbolic link, and your applications won’t know any better.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: This is a nice option. Thanks! However, the folder `/Microsoft Teams Chat Files` still appears at the root of OneDrive cluttering the list of folders.

Comment: I completely agree Joannes. I hate all the clutter that programs put into Documents and/or OneDrive. But it's soooo hard to fight. I think the easiest solution is to create a single folder in Documents or OneDrive that has all the stuff you actually want control over. Then let Windows and other programs clutter up Documents and OneDrive all they want.

Comment: It's [not currently possible](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/how-can-we-change-the-folder-path-of-microsoft/27bbacdf-0752-4ef4-9a4d-6e4c83f5fb47) to move the folder itself.